# Azure API doesn't work for one subscription

Tags: azure

I am using Azure API to create blob storage account.
For my old subscription it works, but after I created a new subscription, and tried to use it, the API fails with error:

```
The client 'xxx' with object id 'xxx' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/write' over scope '/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/xxxx' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.
```

When I try to create it from the UI with that subscription it does work.
How can I solve the issue, so I will be able to use the API also with the new subscription?

Answer (score 1):

Both subscriptions need to be in the same Azure AD directory.  If they are not then you are out of luck (but you can move subscriptions between directories).

Click on your new subscription and go to Access Control. Look for your app registration and grant it the appropriate permission against your subscription.

You can also do this at the storage account level if you want to scope the app's permissions to only that resource.

[image]